# Finding and preventing StackOverflow

Tags: c#, linux, windows

I have a code that seems to work fine on my computer in Visual Studio Code (Windows 11, C#, newest updates and everything up to date), but not on a testing one, which uses Mono Compiler (Linux, C# 7 compatible). The only thing thats different is, where there is *is null*, I changed it to *== null*, since it wouldn't run otherwise.

```
// BitMatrix.cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BitMatrix : IEquatable<BitMatrix>
{
    private BitArray data;
    public int NumberOfRows { get; }
    public int NumberOfColumns { get; }
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public BitMatrix(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns, params int[] bits)
    {
        if (numberOfRows < 1 || numberOfColumns < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Incorrect size of matrix");
        data = new BitArray(numberOfRows * numberOfColumns, false);

        if (bits != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length && i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bits[i] != 0)
                    data[i] = true;
            }
        }

        NumberOfRows = numberOfRows;
        NumberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    }

    public BitMatrix(int[,] bits)
    {
        if (bits == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("bits cannot be null");

        int numberOfRows = bits.GetLength(0);
        int numberOfColumns = bits.GetLength(1);

        if (numberOfRows < 1 || numberOfColumns < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Incorrect size of matrix");

        data = new BitArray(numberOfRows * numberOfColumns, false);

        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
            {
                if (bits[row, col] != 0)
                    data[row * numberOfColumns + col] = true;
            }
        }

        NumberOfRows = numberOfRows;
        NumberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    }

    public BitMatrix(bool[,] bits)
    {
        if (bits == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("bits cannot be null");

        int numberOfRows = bits.GetLength(0);
        int numberOfColumns = bits.GetLength(1);

        if (numberOfRows < 1 || numberOfColumns < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Incorrect size of matrix");

        data = new BitArray(numberOfRows * numberOfColumns, false);

        for (int row = 0; row < numberOfRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < numberOfColumns; col++)
            {
                if (bits[row, col])
                    data[row * numberOfColumns + col] = true;
            }
        }

        NumberOfRows = numberOfRows;
        NumberOfColumns = numberOfColumns;
    }

    public static int BoolToBit(bool boolValue) => boolValue ? 1 : 0;
    public static bool BitToBool(int bit) => bit != 0;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var result = "";
        for (int row = 0; row < NumberOfRows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < NumberOfColumns; col++)
            {
                int index = row * NumberOfColumns + col;
                result += BoolToBit(data[index]);
            }
            result += Environment.NewLine; // dodanie znaku końca linii
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool Equals(BitMatrix? matrix)
    {
        if (matrix is null || NumberOfRows != matrix.NumberOfRows || NumberOfColumns != matrix.NumberOfColumns) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] != matrix.data[i]) return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType()) return false;
        else return Equals((BitMatrix)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + NumberOfRows.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + NumberOfColumns.GetHashCode();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            hash = hash * 23 + data[i].GetHashCode();
        }
        return hash;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(BitMatrix matrix1, BitMatrix matrix2)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(matrix1, matrix2)) return true;

        if (matrix1 is null || matrix2 is null) return false;

        return matrix1.Equals(matrix2);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(BitMatrix matrix1, BitMatrix matrix2)
    {
        return !(matrix1 == matrix2);
    }
}
```

On the main file (Program.cs), when using the following command, it should return True (and on my comp it does!),

```
// `Equals` for the same object
var m1 = new BitMatrix(5, 6);
var m2 = m1;
Console.WriteLine(m1.Equals(m2));
```

but instead it returns

```
Unhandled Exception:
StackOverflowException
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.StackOverflowException: The requested operation caused a stack overflow.
  at BitMatrix.op_Equality (BitMatrix matrix1, BitMatrix matrix2) <0x40c71820 + 0x00004> in <ee17de3584e0451aa17782759cde6afe>:0
```

Comment: In the generic `Equals()`, try `else return Equals((BitMatrix?)obj);` instead of `else return Equals((BitMatrix)obj);`.

Comment: Was not able to [reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VeaytU) .

Comment: So by saying `var m2 = m1;`, BitMatrix is a reference type so that means there is going to be a reference copy. But in your method for `Equals(BitMatrix? matrix)` I don't see a check for reference equality, although you *do* include it in your `==` overload. This edge case will probably resolve this specific issue. But I don't know why it doesn't work across different environments.

Comment: I don't see why the reference and nullability checks should only be present in the operator overload, if you don't plan to actually use the overload. If you want them to be interchangeable then they all should be fully interchangeable (i.e. performing all the same checks), but for your code snippet, `==` is clearly the preferable option to use in all cases

Comment: So to clarify, overloaded operator will be used later, I can't add `else return Equals((BitMatrix?)obj);`, because it spits out an error `./BitMatrixPartial.cs(24,29): error CS0453: The type BitMatrix must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as type parameter T in the generic type or method System.Nullable<T>` and didn't I add nullability checks in both **Equals**?
Also, that version of C# doesn't include `is null`, that's why I used `== null` (at least that what the error says `Feature pattern matching cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 7.0 language specification`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it by just checking the if the objects are the same instances manually in `public bool Equals(BitMatrix matrix)` by adding `if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, matrix)) return true;`.
I suppose Mono Compiler doesn't do it by itself.